# Compute the time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am facing some problems in algorithm course.

How to compute the time complexity of the following algorithm:
I try to put a constant number instead of `n`, and try to know its complexity
but I find myself getting very confused with Big O questions.

```
x=0;

for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)

        x=x+i;
```

I want to know the the steps to solve the problem so I can solve such problems.

Comment: @payeli That's not true. The outer loop executes n^2 times.

Comment: @payeli The loop do depends on `n`.. You can't say it's a constant since it's getting executed `n ^ 2` times.

Comment: @payeli You can assume `t = n * n`, then the complexity will be O(t^2), but `t = n * n`, so in `n` terms it'll be `O(n^2^2) = O(n ^ 4)`.

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity of your code in asymptotic big O notation will be O( n ^ 4 ). The actual number of operations ( which is 'x = x + 1' ) will be close to ( ( n ^ 4 ) / 2 ) times. Let me break it down for you, the first loop execute exactly n^2 times and for each of it's iteration, the nested loop will be iterated over i times. So at worst case it(second loop) will execute n^2 times. In total, it becomes O( n ^ 4 ).

Comment: You say that the actual number of operations is (n^4)/2, but this produces the wrong answer for n=1 (actual: 0, formula: 0.5).

Comment: @Anonymous you are right! it's actually close to (n^4)/2 but not exactly that. I've modified my answer. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is to have a pen and a paper, run it for several values of `n` and try to have a direction. Then, you do the following:

For `n = 0`, the inner loop won't be executed.
For `n = 1`, the inner loop will be executed 1 times.
For `n = 2`, the inner loop will be executed 4 times.
For `n = 3`, the inner loop will be executed 9 times.

"How many times does the outer loop execute?"
"n<sup>2</sup>"

"How many times the inner loop execute?"
"n<sup>2</sup>"

So you conclude that the time-complexity is O(n<sup>4</sup>).

Comment: I don't think your calculations are right. For n=1, the inner loop will be executed 0 times. For n=2, the inner loop will be executed 1+2+3=6 times.

Comment: j can't be 0 for n=1, since i only takes the value 0 (since i<1*1) and the condition on the inner loop is j<0.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables `x`, `i` and `j` are unsigned integral types, the answer is O(1), since both loops can execute at most a limited number of times. For example `sqrt(UINT_MAX)` times if the variables are unsigned ints.

If the variables are signed integral types, the code produces undefined behavior for `n` large enough to produce an overflow, making the question unanswerable.

If you treat the variables as idealised, then you can count exactly the number of times the `x=x+i` statement is executed.

Namely,

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n^2 - 1)
```

This is `(n^2 - 1) * (n^2) / 2` or `(n^4)/2 - (n^2)/2`, which is O(n^4).

Comment: Funny perspective.
In practice, I think this answer is correct. It's a huge O(1) though.

Answer (score 0):

The formal steps to infer the time complexity of your algorithm above:

[image]